# MainActivity puts valid String into Extras for an Intent but the Intent finds null String. What to do?

Tags: android, android-intent, extras

I am baffled by what's happening.

I put the file name "Help" into the Extras of the `Intent` that I then immediately start. (There can't be any problems with this first code block. With breakpoint after `putExtra`, Watch expression `helpIntent.getStringExtra(PACKAGE_NAME + ".filename")` returned `"Help"`.)

```
import static com.dslomer64.sqhell.BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
...
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  public final static String PACKAGE_NAME       = APPLICATION_ID;
...
  @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
  {
    if(item.toString().equals("Help") || item.toString().equals("Acknowledgements"))
    {
      Intent
          helpIntent;
      helpIntent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);

      helpIntent.putExtra(PACKAGE_NAME + ".filename", item.getTitle().toString());

      startActivity(helpIntent);
      return true;
    }
...
}
```

The fun begins in the spawned `Intent`:

``````
public class HelpActivity extends Activity
{
...
  public void showHelp(AssetManager assets, String filename)
  {
    try
    {
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                      filename = null ********* #1
       stream = assets.open(filename); 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////    }

    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
...
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.w("`````Help", "onCreate--bundle info: " + bundle.toString()) ;
    Log.w("`````Help","onCreate--bundle key: " + bundle.getString("filename") );

     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    String fn = bundle.getString((PACKAGE_NAME + ".filename"));
    //     fn = null  ***************************** #2
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    showHelp(getAssets(), fn ); 
  }
``````

The first sign of trouble (#1) was "filename is empty". Tracing back was easy. Now we're at #2, where--just compare--I use the same basic syntax to try to get the filename `"Help"` out of the Extras of the `Intent`. But it's `null`.

I'm not an expert with `Intent` but I've successfully used one a few times in the past.

I guess if I supplied a compilable program that shows the error it would be easier. But ...

If nobody spots anything right off, I'll get on that.

But it's straightforward!

But not.

================

EDIT

I added 2 `Log` statements (see above) and got this output:

``````
    W/`````Help: onCreate--bundle info: 

Bundle[{com.dslomer64.sqhell.filename=Help}]
//////////////////////////////////////^^^^
    W/`````Help: onCreate--bundle key: null
``````

Not sure how this helps since it looks like "Help" is where it should be. And I assume key is null is equivalent to the original problem about filename being null.

============================

EDIT #2: Here's the WHOLE `HelpActivity` class. If this doesn't help, I'll get on the compilable thing:

``````
package com.dslomer64.sqhell;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static android.provider.ContactsContract.Directory.PACKAGE_NAME;

public class HelpActivity extends Activity
{
  Scanner     scDict;
  InputStream stream;
  EditText    help;

  public void showHelp(AssetManager assets, String filename)
  {
    help = /*(EditText)*/ findViewById(R.id.txaHelp);
    try
    {
      stream = assets.open(filename);
    }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    scDict = new Scanner(stream).useDelimiter("\n\r\t ,.:;-( )"); // added (SPACE) recently

    help.getText().clear();
    while(scDict.hasNext())
      help.append(scDict.next());

    hideKeyboard();

    help.setSelection(0);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);

    Log.w("`````Help", "onCreate--bundle info: "  + bundle.toString()) ;
    Log.w("`````Help", "onCreate--bundle key: "   + bundle.getString(PACKAGE_NAME + ".filename"));
    String fn =                                     bundle.getString(PACKAGE_NAME + ".filename");
    showHelp(getAssets(), fn );

  }

}
``````

=========================

In following cricket's advice, I noticed a long line in the `import`area:

```
    import static android.provider.ContactsContract.Directory.PACKAGE_NAME;
```

I don't remember ever seeing such before. So I took it out and got a few errors, wherever `PACKAGE_NAME` was used. Since each line had the "red underline" indicating use keypress 'Alt-Enter' for an easy `import` construction, I found that I HAD TWO CHOICES: the one above and `MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME`.

I assume the previous time I did this, I chose the wrong item to `import`.

All is well.

Spent... too long on this.

Thanks to all who helped and Cricket for steering me in the right direction.

=====================

FINAL EDIT:

All I needed to do all along was delete the long `import` statement. And also pay attention to what I selected after doing it.

Criminey.

I thought I was doing what Cricket suggested all along. Didn't get the funny import in other classes. Why here????

Comment: `bundle.getString("filename")`... You're missing the package name there

Comment: @cricket_007--I guess ... okay. Good catch. But then that line will return null like the line after it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it looks like "Help" is where it should be.

It does

> ... key is null

Its actually the value, but you're  getting the value of the key `"filename"`, not `PACKAGE_NAME + ".filename"`, which is what you used in the putExtra.

The keys don't match, so the value is null

Suggestion: define your own constant like

```
public static final String FILENAME_EXTRA = APPLICATION_ID + ".filename";
```

and use that in all classes

Additionally your Scanner and everything requiring the file to be opened should be inside the try block.

Comment: See my comment above, just after yours.

Answer (score 1):

you put data in the `Intent`, not the `Bundle`.

So, try `String fn = getIntent().getStringExtra(PACKAGE_NAME + ".filename")`.Then you will find what you want.

Comment: An Intent contains a Bundle. They call the exact same methods in the Android source

Answer (score 0):

you are using a wrong key when retrieving the value.

``````
  Log.w("`````Help","onCreate--bundle key: " + bundle.getString(PACKAGE_NAME + ".filename") );
``````